# r crossed nested random effects lme4

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am new to this forum. I try to find the appropriate model for the following data set with lme4:

[image]

Each individual subject goes through 3 conditions ("Group", within-subject factor). These 3 conditions include 9 items (3 items in each condition, but the items differ in each condition). Score (4th column not represented above) is a continuous dependant variable (reaction time).
I am interested in the fixed effect of the "Cond" variable and also would like to take into account the dependencies between my factors, but I have difficulties to know if my factors should be considered as nested or crossed.
Does the following model seems correct to you ?
Score~1+Cond+(1|Subject)+(1|item)
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at the GLMM FAQ (google it), or any of the other nested/crossed questions on this site, yet?

Comment: Maybe this short code-example helps: https://github.com/strengejacke/mixed-models-snippets/blob/master/nested_fully-crossed_cross-classified_models.R You can also check if two factors are nested, fully crossed or cross-classified with `sjmisc::is_crossed()`, `sjmisc::is_nested()` or `sjmisc::is_cross_classified()`, see here: https://strengejacke.github.io/sjmisc/reference/index.html